# How to ensure numeric values are ingested as "Integers" or "Floats" in Python

Tags: python, pandas, object, types, data-conversion

I have a large dataset derived from the ingestion of a CSV file.  Every time I pull the data in using df = pd.read_csv, the features in the dataset show up as "objects". This leads me to the following questions:

1. How do I ensure integers and floats are pulled in as integers and floats and not "objects"?  Ive never seen this "object" issue before.
2. Is there a way to convert "object" to "int" or "float" as I don't see a series of commands to enable me to do so?

Thanks for any input in advance.

I've looked and tried everything; I see no means of converting "objects"
I do not know the cause of this data import issue.

Comment: Can you post how you're calling `pd.read_csv()` ? Some options affect how Pandas picks dtypes.

Comment: This can be used to change dtypes: https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.astype.html

Answer (score 0):

The original post did not offer a
[reprex](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).
Here, let me make one for you:

```
>>> df = pd.DataFrame({'a': [1], 'b': [2]})
>>> df.dtypes
a    int64
b    int64
dtype: object
>>> 
>>> df = pd.DataFrame({'a': [1, 8], 'b': [2, 'nine']})
>>> df.dtypes
a     int64
b    object
dtype: object
>>> df
   a     b
0  1     2
1  8  nine
```

Using [.astype()](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.astype.html)
on this yields yields no joy, it just blows up with a ValueError
reporting that "nine" is an invalid literal.

But we can clean that column.
Pandas `NA` to the rescue!

```
def clean(n):
    try:
        int(n)  # Evaluated for side effects -- will `raise` if invalid.
        return n
    except ValueError:
        return pd.NA  # Roughly this is a `NaN`, but it's not floating point.
```

```
>>> df['b_clean'] = df.b.apply(clean).astype('Int64')
>>> df.dtypes
a           int64
b          object
b_clean     Int64
dtype: object
>>> df
   a     b  b_clean
0  1     2        2
1  8  nine     <NA>
```

Feel free to just overwrite `df['b']` if you no longer
need the old rubbish values.

---

EDIT

mozway observes that one could also do:

```
>>> df['b_clean'] = pd.to_numeric(df.b, errors='coerce').astype('Int64')
>>> df.dtypes
a           int64
b          object
b_clean     Int64
dtype: object
```

Comment: The canonical way to convert to numeric in pandas is [`to_numeric`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.to_numeric.html) with `errors='coerce'`